# Not able to run node.js program in command prompt

Tags: node.js

[error on executing the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXd4y.png)I am beginner to node.js .I have followed all the steps from the below blog:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

I got the node version and npm version too.
But not getting the output when I try to run the js file from cmd.

```
console.log('Node is installed!');
```

the content of the js file is mentioned in the above line.

Please help me out!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the "hello.js" file in same directory as where you are trying to run the `node hello.js` command?

Comment: did this solve your problem bro?

Comment: Or, to make sure node is setup properly just type "node". That will give you the node command line and allow you to run js directly. To run a js file named test.js that resides in same directory as you are currently in on command prompt, you can just type "node test".

Answer (score 0):

Its Seems there is no **hello.j**s in **c drive** or in **wrong directory**

Goto any folder and make your hello.js and then navigate to that folder in cmd then write

```
node hello.js  // .js is optional
```

[image]

in the picture above you can i receive error helloo cant find module becoz i `dont have any file with name helloo.js`

suppose your file is in D drive then goto **D** drive and wirte

[image]

Your can make simple **hello.js** server

```
//Lets re   quire/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');
//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 
//We need a function which handles requests and send response
//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
});
//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```